# is it possitble to do mappingTarget Map from Object in mapstruct?

Tags: java, mapstruct

The application I used has lots of json fields in entity.
So I should update only the fields I know.
You can see the below code.

```java
@Mapper(
    config = CommonMapper.class,
    nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE,
    nullValueCheckStrategy = NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS)
public interface ProductMapper {

  @Mapping(target = "id", source = "id")  // it is not working
  void updateMapFromProduct(@MappingTarget Map<String, Object> map, Product product);
}
```

so I want to see the ProductMapperImpl like this.
is it possible?

```java
@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2022-09-02T10:04:50+0900",
    comments = "version: 1.4.2.Final, compiler: IncrementalProcessingEnvironment from gradle-language-java-7.5.jar, environment: Java 11.0.11 (AdoptOpenJDK)"
)
@Component
public class ProductMapperImpl implements ProductMapper {

    @Override
    public void updateMapFromProduct(Map<String, Object> map, Product product) {
        if ( map == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        map.put("id", product.getId());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mapping from a Bean into a Map is currently not supported in MapStruct. There is an open [feature request](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/2504) that you can follow to track this functionality.